# can I create a simple dependency property to bind Margin?

Tags: wpf

I have a custom control and want to bind a user defined margin. In the client code where 
 I try to use it, it shows an error. It says -

"'0}'string cannot be converted to Length"

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty MarginProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("Margin", typeof (Thickness), typeof 
 (TestControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(Thickness)));

    public Thickness Margin
     {
         get { return (Thickness) GetValue(MarginProperty); }
         set { SetValue(MarginProperty, value); }
     }
```

Is there any issue with my dependency property?

Thanks & Regads

Comment: Post more code how are you using this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Margin`property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin(v=vs.110).aspx) of any FrameworkElement already, what are you trying to achieve creating a dep property with the same name and same type?